# declaring static variable after static initialzer

Tags: java, static, instance, declaration, instantiation

The following code compiles successfully. As per my understanding variables have to be declared before using them then what exactly is happening here

```
class A {
static {
    y=20;
    z=10;
}
static int z;
static int y=30;
{
    w=10;
}
int w;
public static void main(String args[]){
     System.out.println(y);
}
}
```

Modified the question after reading the comments.
Here the output is 30.
So variable declaration happens first, then all the initialization statements are executed as per order of appearance

Comment: *"As per my understanding variables have to be declared before using"* And why do you think that the placement of the block and the variable matters here?

Comment: *Local* variables have to be declared before the first use. Fields, not so much...

Comment: Both links don't work as a dupe, but they (implicitly) say that placements of fields can vary: [Placement of instance variable declarations](//stackoverflow.com/q/218573) // [Java best practice - Is declaring the constructor before the class variables a bad thing?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10264447)

Comment: modified the question to cover additional scenario

Comment: The examples in [JLS Sec 8.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) look instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> variables have to be declared before using them

This is only partially right. If you are in a method and you do this:

```
System.out.println(i);
int i = 0;
```

Obviously it won't compile.

But when you are declaring a variable at class level, this rule does no hold. In your code, just because `w`'s declaration is written a few lines after it is being used (`w = 10;`), it does not mean that the line `int w;` is executed after the line `w = 10;`.

Think of it like this: the compiler will see all the static fields' declarations (class level variables) first, then all the non-static fields', then the code blocks (constructors, methods etc) in the class. In your code:

```
class A {
    static {
        z=10;
    }
    static int z;
    {
        w=10;
    }
    int w;
}
```

the compiler sees `z` first, then `w`. Then let's suppose you access `A` for the first time in some other parts of your code. Now the static block is executed (`z=10;`). Let's suppose again that you are actually creating a new instance of `A`, now `w=10;` will get executed.

Comment: modified the question for completeness

Comment: @wib The behaviour you encountered is because statements like `int y=30;` are executed after the static blocks. So the compiler sees the declaration first, then run the static blocks, then executed the `y=30` part.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are declared by the classloader when it loads the class.

Static block will be evaluated first time the class is accessed so in that time the member variables will be declared, so the order does not really matter

Comment: modified the question. what happens when variables are declared and initialized in one statement?